# Block previous days and 48hrs after current date in Daterangepicker

Tags: jquery

I am using a Daterangepicker library and I am trying to block out all days before the current day and 48hrs after current day from being selected.

Comment: Which plugin you are using? There are lot of plugins with different options

Comment: We need much more detail to be able to help you effectively. That said, most datepicker libraries will have min/max properties. Check the documentation.

Comment: yes. I am using daterangepicker library @RavishaHesh. 
And yes it has min/max properties and Alex below has helped me with the fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use minDate and maxDate options like below:

```
<input type="text" name="datetimes" />

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    minDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
    maxDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(48, 'hour'),
    locale: {
      format: 'M/DD hh:mm A'
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have something close to what I want but your solution is working reverse. It's blocking all the days and only leaving current date plus 48hrs available for selection but I have figured it from your code and this gave me what I wanted `maxDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(48, 'hour')`. Thanks a lot